# TYPO3 Installation error: Invalid service "lowlevel.configuration.module.provider.webhooks"

Tags: installation, typo3, typo3-12.x

I tried to install TYPO3 on macOS with the help of DDEV as documented on the TYPO3 website.

But I get an internal server error on step 4. What do i need to do to fix this?

> 1/1) Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException
>
> Invalid service "lowlevel.configuration.module.provider.webhooks":
> class
> "TYPO3\CMS\Lowlevel\ConfigurationModuleProvider\AbstractProvider" not
> found while loading "TYPO3\CMS\Webhooks\ConfigurationModuleProvider\WebhookTypesProvider"

I also tried installing it directly without DDEV with composer, but I got the same error.

Comment: See here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100844

Comment: Fixed an released in TYPO3 v12.4.2: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/79128

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick fix until official patch will be released:

remove the webhooks package (if you don't need this):

```
composer remove typo3/cms-webhooks
```

Or add the lowlevel package like so:

```
composer require typo3/cms-lowlevel
```

Comment: The same affects browser installer.