# TYPO3 installation via Docker and DDEV: How can I resolve the never-ending loading after entering my TYPO3 admin details in the TYPO3 install tool?

Tags: docker, composer-php, typo3, ddev

I have created a local installation of TYPO3 using Docker and DDEV but can't get past the Install Tool. After I enter the details for my administrative user and click continue, it just loads forever. I am using TYPO3 12.4.1.

I have tried reloading the site and reenter the information as well as restarting my DDEV project, which all lead to the same result.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow (so). please read your question again, how should anyone not you, not having your computer in front answer this? you shared no configuration files, there is no trouble-shooting information apart from that you restarted ddev - which is close to nothing, all we can say is that ddev is kind of working? please consider a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Are you sure it is related to Docker or Composer after all?

Comment: Try the exact recipe in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#typo3 and see how it goes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Typo3 12.4.1.
To fix it you can install following package during the installation, before you start the GUI based setup in the browser:

```
ddev composer require typo3/cms-lowlevel
```

The same error occurs, if you use the setup in the console with the CLI command instead of the browser based GUI setup. But in this case an error message is shown and the error is more obvious.
([TYPO3 Installation error: Invalid service "lowlevel.configuration.module.provider.webhooks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213382/typo3-installation-error-invalid-service-lowlevel-configuration-module-provide)).

Comment: The described error is fixed in Typo3 12.4.2.